# Shiny web application using twitter data

Tags: r

I am trying to create a Shiny application wherein the user inputs a text string to search on twitter along with the option to choose the number of tweets to fetch. I want the output to be a table of the last 10 tweets and a word cloud of the tweets fetched. I am not able to download the tweets and get the correct word cloud output using the following code:
`library(shiny)
    shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
      headerPanel("Tweets hunter"),
      sidebarPanel(textInput("n1", "Enter a search term", ""),
                   sliderInput("number", "Select a number of tweets",
                               min=10,max=3200, value = 5),
                   submitButton(text = "Run")),
      mainPanel(
        h4("Last 10 tweets"),
        tableOutput("table"),
        plotOutput("w1"))
    ))`

    Server Code:

```
library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)
library(plyr)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
library(stringr)
library(NLP)
library(tm)
library(devtools)
library(tidytext)
library(data.table)
library(wordcloud)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(sentimentr)
library(SentimentAnalysis)
library(syuzhet)
library(pander)
library(httr)
library(qdap)
library(shiny)
consumer_key<-"****"
consumer_secret<-"****"
access_token<-"****"
access_secret<-"****"
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key,consumer_secret,access_token,access_secret)
shinyServer(function(input,output){
  rawData <- (function(){
    tweet <- searchTwitter(input$n1, n=input$number)
    twListToDF(tweet)
  })
  output$table <- renderTable(function(){
    head(rawData()[1],n=10)
  })
  output$w1 <- renderPlot(function(){
    tweet.text <- enc2native(rawData()$text)
    tweet.text <- tolower(tweet.text)
    tweet.text <- removeWords(tweet.text,c(stopwords(input$lang),"rt"))
    tweet.text <- removePunctuation(tweet.text, TRUE)
    tweet.text <- unlist(strsplit(tweet.text,""))
    word <- sort(table(tweet.text),TRUE)
    word1 <- head(word,n=15)
    wordcloud(names(word1),word1,random.color = TRUE,colors = rainbow(10),scale = c(15,2))
  })
})

For the above code i am getting the error : Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'xtable' applied to an object of class "function"
```